# "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1" when trying to install python-language-server

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-language-server

I've below pip installed in my system

```
    $ pip --version
    pip 19.3.1 from /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

python version installed in my system is -

```
    $ python --version
    Python 3.8.3
```

I'm trying to install `python-language-server` and encountered below error -

> Running setup.py install for ujson ... error
>      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>       command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yoqmgayp/ujson/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yoqmgayp/ujson/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-h4azsb93/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
>           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-yoqmgayp/ujson/
>      Complete output (16 lines):
>      Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'filter'
>      running install
>      running build
>      running build_ext
>      building 'ujson' extension
>      creating build
>      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
>      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/python
>      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/lib
>      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I./python -I./lib -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c ./python/ujson.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/./python/ujson.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
>      In file included from ./python/ujson.c:39:
>      ./python/py_defines.h:39:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>         39 | #include 
>            |          ^~~~~~~~~~
>      compilation terminated.
>      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yoqmgayp/ujson/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yoqmgayp/ujson/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-h4azsb93/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Below is my OS details -

```
    $ lsb_release -a
    LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
    Distributor ID: Fedora
    Description:    Fedora release 32 (Thirty Two)
    Release:        32
    Codename:       ThirtyTwo
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: yeap. It solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the word message, it tells you what is wrong

```
./python/py_defines.h:39:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

It says it can't find the header file. Ask `dnf` about what provides it:

```
sudo dnf provides '*/Python.h'
```

Then install that package (`sudo dnf install ...`) and retry your original command.